# "Building boot caches on boot helper partition failed" error selecting rEFInd

Tags: macos, boot, mac, partitioning, refind

I have rEFInd (0.9.2) installed on my Mac in its own hfs+ partition. This allows rEFInd to appear as an option on the "Startup Disk" window under "System Preferences". Below is an image of the "Startup Disk" window.

[image]

Under Yosemite (OS X 10.10.5), I had no problem selecting the rEFInd partition. Under El Captain (OS X 10.11), I get the following error message.

[image]

So, what changed and how do I repair it?

My Mac is a iMac (20 inch, Mid 2007). The model identifier is iMac7,1.

### Update 1

This update was entered after Rod posted his answer.

The problem posted in the above question does not appear to be caused by System Integrity Protection (SIP). If I turn SIP off, the result is the same.

However since you have brought up SIP, I will add the following. With SIP turned off, I have no problem installing rEFInd using the command

```
sudo ./install.sh --ownhfs /dev/disk0s9
```

where `disk0s9` is the small partition reserved just for rEFInd. Also the following command works with SIP turned off.

```
sudo bless --device /dev/disk0s9 --setBoot
```

Nether commands work properly with SIP turned on.

### Update 2 (Posted 6-11-2020)

[RustyShackleford](https://superuser.com/users/879530/rustyshackleford) posted a comment to one of [my answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392518/using-refind-to-get-around-lack-of-boot-screen-when-using-unsupported-gpu-in-mac/392527#392527) regarding a section from one of Rod Smith's websites titled [Using Startup Disk to Adjust Your Boot Priority](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html#startup_disk) . This section states the Startup Disk pane of macOS System Preferences can be used to make rEFInd the default to boot. For test purposes, I installed rEFInd (0.12.0) in a JHFS+ partition on a 2013 iMac. High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6) and Catalina (macOS 10.15.4) was installed in an APFS container. Windows 10 was also installed. Below is what was shown in the Startup Disk pane of High Sierra System Preferences.

[image]

Testing using either High Sierra and Catalina resulted in the following error message. Disabling SIP did not change the error message.

[image]

If anyone knows of a configuration since Yosemite were rEFInd can be made the default from the Startup Disk pane, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installed as you've done it, rEFInd uses critical filenames normally used by OS X's own boot loader, but on its own partition. It looks like OS X 10.11's Startup Disk tool may be relying on additional files that rEFInd's `install.sh` doesn't create. If so, creating appropriate "dummy" files might fix the problem -- but figuring out what files to create might be difficult.

Another possibility is that the new System Integrity Protection (aka "rootless") feature of OS X 10.11 is causing problems. If so, disabling this feature, as described [here,](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) should fix the problem; but this is a new security feature, so you should read up and decide whether you want to disable it.

You might consider trying the `bless` command to set the boot device manually, as described in step #8 under [the OS X installation instructions for rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#osx) I don't know if this will work with System Integrity Protection enabled, though. (Using `bless` manually to set a boot loader on an EFI System Partition does *not* work with System Integrity Protection enabled, but I haven't tried it with a separate HFS+ partition.)

Note: I maintain rEFInd, and will look into this issue myself as time permits. If I can find a good solution, I'll include it in a future release of rEFInd.

Comment: I updated my question based on your answer.

Comment: Then I'd say the issue is most probably one of the Startup Disk tool looking for, and failing to find, some additional files that `install.sh` doesn't create.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same trouble as you, until I found this blog post:

[Configuring rEFInd boot manager as your startup disk on a Mac](http://davidjb.com/blog/2015/06/configuring-refind-boot-manager-as-your-startup-disk-on-a-mac/)

The author, [DavidJB.com](http://davidjb.com/), describes how you can set the default startup disk by pressing the <kbd>control</kbd> key at the same time as selecting the startup disk from the Startup Manager. (You need to hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key during the boot process to invoke to the Startup Manager). The author suggests holding the <kbd>control</kbd> key when clicking the disk, but I didn't have a pointer, so just held the <kbd>control</kbd> key when I pressed the <kbd>return</kbd> key after selecting the desired disk.

So far, it has taken me straight to [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which I have installed on a separate HFS+ partition, every time I've restarted since then.

Comment: @Rod Smith: This is a fascinating way to set rEFInd as the default at startup. It certainly avoids having to deal with System Integrity Protection (SIP). This also works when rEFInd is installed in a EFI partition.

Comment: This really is not the answer to my question, but I did find it useful. Unfortunately, your answer was also posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/316657/how-to-define-from-what-partition-to-boot-by-default-in-os-x) by user [slck](http://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) back in 2011.

Comment: Thank you this works for me. I do not use rEFInd, instead installed Arch Linux root on ext4 with GRUB on a vfat partition with the required file structure.